# how to get Even/Odd id numbers from a database table in codeigniter

Tags: mysql, database, codeigniter

I am new in codeigniter and just stacked in a query to solve a report for an emergency project. Please help me Codeigniter's Experts.

- I have a large database table and wants to show only Odd/Even Data rows from that table which will filtered by a table Field named is "sale_id". I tried it in PHPMyadmin in raw coding and it's worked for me. But can not apply in Codeigniter.

`SELECT * FROM ospos_pak_sub_cat WHERE id %2 =0;`

Worked for me in raw PHP Coding. How can I use it in Codeigniter. I used a Where Condition already on that query and now want to add the new query. 
Existing Where condition is given below, which is working fine.

`$this->db->where('sale_date BETWEEN "'. $inputs['start_date']. '" and "'. $inputs['end_date'].'"');`

It is working and I tried the code below to get the solution which is not working and getting error.

`$this->db->where('sale_id %2'=> 0);`

Getting error with this line. says--

`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW)`

Please help me to get the solutions. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your Model, just write the query like that:

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('ospos_pak_sub_cat');
$this->db->where('sale_id %2=', 0);
$query_result = $this->db->get();
$result = $query_result->result();
```

You missed the '=' in your code. Hope, it will work.

Comment: Thanks a lot Tahsin Abrar bro. I tried with your solution after a few days back and got the solutions.

Answer (score 1):

in SQL the % character is a wildcard rather than a modulo which would explain your error. you can use the MOD function instead  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_mod

so the resulting code would be :

```
    $this->db->where('MOD(sale_id ,2) => 0');
```

Comment: That give me an error. Using this query `$this->db->where('MOD(sale_id ,2)', 0);` will work

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but i think it will work try this line
`$this->db->where('sale_id %2',0);`

Comment: Thanks for suggest.. But not worked. Getting this error.

A Database Error Occurred

Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '0 GROUP BY `sale_id` ORDER BY `sale_date`' at line 6

Comment: there is some bug in that try this line i have run this and get the result you are looking for $this->db->where('sale_id % 2 = ',0);

Comment: Hi, in SQL the % character is a wildcard rather than a modulo which would explain your error. you can use the MOD function instead http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_mod

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, you can add the new condition in existing where condition as like below

```
$this->db->where('(sale_date BETWEEN "'. $inputs['start_date']. '" and "'. $inputs['end_date'].')" and ((sale_id % 2) = 0)');
```